# Modelling differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The half-life of a radioactive isotope is the amount of time it takes for a quantity of radioactive material to decay to one-half of its original amount.

a. The half-life of Carbon 14 is 5230 years. Determine the decay-rate parameter $\lambda$ for C-14.

The general solution is $r(t) = ce^{\lambda t}$ and that $\lambda = \frac{-1}{t}(\frac{r}{r_0})$ but does C-14 denote the amount of the isotope at the initial stage? I don't understand why $r_0 =\frac{r}{2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C-14 is just the name of the isotope it is not an amount of the substance.

The amount at any time is given by,

$$r(t) = Ce^{\lambda t}$$

The amount at a later time $t+\tau$ should be half as much (\tau is the half life).

$$\frac{1}{2} r(t)= r(t + \tau) = C e^{\lambda (t+\tau)} = C e^{\lambda t} e^{\lambda \tau} = r(t) e^{\lambda \tau} $$

From this we conclude that,

$$ \frac{1}{2}  = e^{\lambda \tau}$$

$$ \frac{\ln(1/2)}{  \tau} = \lambda $$

Comment: Thanks. I think $r =\frac{r_0}{2}$, this gives me $\lambda = \frac{ln(2)}{5230}$. Also, if Iodine 131 has a half-life of 8 days, does that mean $t = \frac{8}{365}$?

Comment: That's correct though you need to remember that according to the notation of your question your lambda needs a minus sign. Whether to use $t=8/365$ **years** vs $t=8$ **days** is just a matter of convention. All this changes are the units of the decay constant.